# Pattern to avoid virtual tables

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Is there a design pattern that avoids the use of virtual function tables for parent-child classes. I considered using CRTP but this is a compile time solution and I need an initialization time solution as it will be based on variable at creation time. I essentially want to be able to set a variable to either object A or object B at initialization based on a run-time flag. I could use the factory pattern, but that incurs the run-time cost of using virtual function tables.

Something like:

```
class A {
    void do_something() {}
};
class B { 
    void do_something() {}
};

?? A_or_B(bool flag) {return flag ? new A() : new B();)

int main(bool flag)
{
    ?? ab = A_or_B(flag);
    ab.do_something(); // without VFT, prefer it to have same performance as A a; a.do_something();
}
```

- CRTP pattern - compile time solution and I need runtime solution.
- Factory Pattern - runtime virtual function tables kill performance.

Comment: Don't use virtual functions?

Comment: Have you actually done any measurements that demonstrate that "runtime virtual function tables kill performance" or are you just taking that as an axiom?

Comment: What you want to do is select a function based on run time information. This has an inherent run time cost, which is the cost you would pay from just using a virtual table.

Comment: It's impossible to do runtime polymorphism at compile time.

Comment: there are some interesting videos on youtube about virtualisme by Sean Parent.

Comment: The first rule of optimization is: Don’t do it. The second rule of optimization (for experts only) is: Don’t do it yet.

Comment: @engf-010 Share some links, please?

Comment: @Evg: too many to mention ,all of them are interesting (some more than others)

Comment: Can you make the flag a template parameter? (remember that template parameters are not limited to classes)

Answer (score 0):

First, if the real problem is performance, chances are nothing you do is going to help a whole lot. If you have to figure out what you're dealing with a runtime, there's going to be a runtime cost to doing that, regardless of how you do it--and virtual functions generally do that fairly well.

That said, there are cases where you have two classes you don't want related via an inheritance hierarchy, even though you want polymorphic behavior. In such a case, you might consider using `std::variant` with `std::visit`.

For example, here's a working example of roughly the idea you seem to be trying for in your question:

```cpp
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    void do_something() const { std::cout << "A\n"; }
};
class B { 
public:
    void do_something() const { std::cout << "B\n"; }
};

using AorB = std::variant<A, B>;

int main(int argc, char **agv) {

    AorB x;
    if (argc == 1)
        x = A();
    else   
        x = B();

    std::visit([](auto const &item) { item.do_something(); }, x);
}
```

So if we run this, we get:

```cpp
Box:~/src$ ./a.out
A
Box:~/src$ ./a.out 1
B
```

So we're getting polymorphic behavior without (exactly) a VFT. It's even *possible* (though far from certain) that this might have somewhat better performance than a virtual function. With a virtual function involved, we have a pointer to an object, which contains a pointer to a vtable, which contains a pointer to a function we're going to invoke, so we have three levels of indirection involved<sup>1</sup>. That gives us a pretty decent chance of things like cache misses, which can clearly hurt performance. Much like you showed, we also typically end up allocating the object(s) on the free store instead of as local variables. That can carry a significant cost in itself.

With `std::variant` we basically have something roughly like:

```cpp
struct {
    int valid_entry;
    union {
       A a;
       B b;
    };
};
```

No indirection, just a union of the possible types, and something to indicate which is valid at a given time. In your case, where you're selecting between A and B at initialization, branches based on the type contained in the union should be highly predictable. So you never know--there's actually at least a decent chance that it *could* be faster than using a virtual function. Maybe not, and even if it is faster, probably not enough to care, but possibly faster anyway.

The real reason to do this is usually more about design--A and B simply aren't related in a way that's modeled well by inheritance, and you don't want to warp your design by using inheritance where it isn't a good fit (which, to be honest, it often isn't).

---

1. I suppose I'm morally obliged to point out that what I've described isn't officially required--it's just how all known compilers actually work.